# Getting value at JSP Page from applet

Tags: java, jsp, applet

I don't know how to get value of applet at JSP.  A value is set by user (in the applet).  I want to display this value on some different JSP.

Can anybody give some guidance on this?

Comment: Hi Andrew ,value of Applet means some value is set by user on  i want to display this value on some different jsp page

Answer (score 1):

An applet can construct an URL containing the user data as a name/value pair<sup>1</sup>.  It can then use the show document method<sup>2</sup> of the applet context to call the other JSP.

1. http://our.com/answer.jsp?name1=value1&name2=value2
2. [`AppletContext.showDocument(URL)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#showDocument%28java.net.URL%29)

Answer (score 0):

use the `<jsp:plugin>` tag you can refer to the [tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSP/JspAppletPlugin.htm) for details.

Answer (score 0):

**JSP is a server-side thing while applet runs in browser** so why and how should these communicate ?
If you need to read some data from an applet and insert them to a page, just [make the applet scriptable and call its method](http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/DOMM-4U8FM6) .